Should I use Query or Select with Drizzle ORM?
I'm using Drizzle ORM with a Postgres database. It's not obvious to me when to use Select vs. Query to access data. For example:
db.select().from(schema.users);
// OR
db.query.users.findMany()

The one advantage I see for using select() is that the the type is unknown when using query:
// select() expected type:
Promise<{
    id: string;
    email: string;
}[]>

// query expected type:
const user: {
    [x: string]: unknown;
}[]

The documentation says query can be used for accessing relations:

Relational queries are meant to provide you with a great developer experience for querying nested relational data from an SQL database, avoiding multiple joins and complex data mappings.

Is that the only time it should be used?

So far, I haven't had a need to use query(). I can get anything done with select().

I highly recommend Orange ORM. https://github.com/alfateam/orange-orm .
It is not new, but has existed on npm since 2014 (previously known as rdb).
It is mature, reliable and has a straightforward syntax. It supports mysql, mssql, postgres, oracle, sap ase and sqlite.
It does not separate query and select.
You can also do nested updates/inserts.
